# How to request data from json in d3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I built this bar chart in D3, It can be viewed here(http://jsfiddle.net/YQthy/). I want to replace the random data with data from this json database.

```
{
  "description" : "Cheese, caraway",
  "group" : "Dairy and Egg Products",
  "id" : 1008,
  "manufacturer" : "",
  "nutrients" : [
     {
        "description" : "Protein",
        "group" : "Composition",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 25.18
     },
     {
        "description" : "Total lipid (fat)",
        "group" : "Composition",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 29.2
     },
     {
        "description" : "Carbohydrate, by difference",
        "group" : "Composition",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 3.060
     },
     {
        "description" : "Energy",
        "group" : "Energy",
        "units" : "kcal",
        "value" : 376.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Water",
        "group" : "Composition",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 39.28
     },
     {
        "description" : "Fiber, total dietary",
        "group" : "Composition",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Calcium, Ca",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 673.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Iron, Fe",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.64
     },
     {
        "description" : "Magnesium, Mg",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 22.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Phosphorus, P",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 490.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Potassium, K",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 93.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Sodium, Na",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 690.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Zinc, Zn",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 2.94
     },
     {
        "description" : "Copper, Cu",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.0240
     },
     {
        "description" : "Manganese, Mn",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.0210
     },
     {
        "description" : "Selenium, Se",
        "group" : "Elements",
        "units" : "mcg",
        "value" : 14.5
     },
     {
        "description" : "Vitamin A, IU",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "IU",
        "value" : 1054.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Retinol",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mcg",
        "value" : 262.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Vitamin A, RAE",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mcg_RAE",
        "value" : 271.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Vitamin C, total ascorbic acid",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Thiamin",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.0310
     },
     {
        "description" : "Riboflavin",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.45
     },
     {
        "description" : "Niacin",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.18
     },
     {
        "description" : "Vitamin B-6",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 0.0740
     },
     {
        "description" : "Folate, total",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mcg",
        "value" : 18.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Vitamin B-12",
        "group" : "Vitamins",
        "units" : "mcg",
        "value" : 0.27
     },
     {
        "description" : "Cholesterol",
        "group" : "Other",
        "units" : "mg",
        "value" : 93.0
     },
     {
        "description" : "Fatty acids, total saturated",
        "group" : "Other",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 18.584
     },
     {
        "description" : "Fatty acids, total monounsaturated",
        "group" : "Other",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 8.275
     },
     {
        "description" : "Fatty acids, total polyunsaturated",
        "group" : "Other",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.83
     },
     {
        "description" : "Tryptophan",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.324
     },
     {
        "description" : "Threonine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.896
     },
     {
        "description" : "Isoleucine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 1.563
     },
     {
        "description" : "Leucine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 2.412
     },
     {
        "description" : "Lysine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 2.0950
     },
     {
        "description" : "Methionine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.659
     },
     {
        "description" : "Cystine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.126
     },
     {
        "description" : "Phenylalanine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 1.326
     },
     {
        "description" : "Tyrosine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 1.216
     },
     {
        "description" : "Valine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 1.682
     },
     {
        "description" : "Arginine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.952
     },
     {
        "description" : "Histidine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.884
     },
     {
        "description" : "Alanine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.711
     },
     {
        "description" : "Aspartic acid",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 1.618
     },
     {
        "description" : "Glutamic acid",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 6.16
     },
     {
        "description" : "Glycine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 0.439
     },
     {
        "description" : "Proline",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 2.838
     },
     {
        "description" : "Serine",
        "group" : "Amino Acids",
        "units" : "g",
        "value" : 1.472
     }
  ],
  "portions" : [
     {
        "amount" : 1,
        "grams" : 28.35,
        "unit" : "oz"
     }
  ],
  "tags" : []
```

}

I want the value of the parent node (cheese, Caraway) to be the variable. It will be selected from the drop down. Then, the description in the child node is to be the label and the "value" as data.

Comment: number of child node will always same ?

Comment: So save the structure above in a variable?

Comment: no of child in nutrients  will always same ?

Comment: @NitishKumar The child nodes will be an array of 30 objects. the above code shows just 3 of the 30. Also, It will be about 1000 Parent Nodes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I would, but I don't know if that will work because of the 1000 Parent nodes. I don't want 1000 variables. Im sure there's a more efficient way.

Comment: Ok, so put them into an array. Sorry, it's not clear to me what you're asking at all.

Comment: @NitishKumar The example you provided worked as I intended. I had to research some of the steps you took because it was difficult to understand. I am new to programming in general. I came to the conclusion that it may be better to display the data across (4) charts in a grid fashion (determined by nutrient group) since the dataset is so large. I updated my post with an example of (1) of the many arrays to put perspective on what I want to achieve.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I want to be able to access the Json data to feed the chart based on the group (amino acids, vitamans, elements) etc. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I try my best to be, I'm still trying to familiarize myself with appropriate terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I added dropdown select box on html.

```
<select class="my"></select>
```

where option will come from json.

and i added some own function.

```
 var l = json.length, i, dd, filterData = [], defaultSelected = '';
  defaultSelected = json[0].id;
 for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
   dd = json[i];

filterData[dd.id] = dd.nutrients;
  d3.select("select.my")
    .append('option')
    .attr("value", dd.id)
    .append("text")
    .text(dd.description);
}
```

and so on ...

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dR8Yj/)